# pass an array objects in Corona with class

Tags: android, class, lua, coronasdk

I'm creating an app with Corona structured in Class and I have a problem when I want pass an array objects for create an object.
I have this:

**main.lua**

```
local SurpriseBoxClass = require("SurpriseBox")
local BoxClass = require("Box")

local box1 = BoxClass.new('palo', 'images/chestClose.gif', 'OPEN')
local box2 = BoxClass.new('moneda', 'images/chestClose.gif', 'OPEN')
boxes = { box1, box2 }

local game = SurpriseBoxClass.new(boxes)
```

**SurpriseBox.lua**

```
local SurpriseBox = {}
local SurpriseBox_mt = { __index = SurpriseBox }

function SurpriseBox.new(boxesAux)
 local object = {
   boxes = boxesAux
 }
 return setmetatable( object, SurpriseBox_mt )
end
```

The problem is when I want to print the content of array in a method of SurpriseBox, and the program said me that the array is nil if for example I do this:

```
print(boxes[0])
```

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua tables are 1-based.

Try `print(boxes[1], boxes[2])`.

It will print the table id. If you need to print the contents of the table, you must iterate over its fields, or [use a custom printer that does it for you](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) (see "Print a table recursively").

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm starting with this language... =)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the function `SupriseBox.new(boxesAux)` (where I gather you desire to do the printing):

In `object`, you are associating the key `"boxes"` with the table `boxesAux`. This to access the contents of `boxesAux` via `object` you must go through the following process:

`object["boxes"]` or `object.boxes` will get you to `boxesAux`, to go into that you need the superscripting i.e `[1]`

```
print(object["boxes"][1]) --etc..
print(object.boxes[1]) --etc..
```

Note that, this will now give you `box1`. If you want to print a meaningful display of it's content (that is if the class isn't overloaded) you should use a pretty printing library.